# NSBitmapImageRep from duration for animated GIF

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have two animated gifs:
http://d-32.com/uploads/gif1.gif and http://d-32.com/uploads/gif2.gif

When using NSBitmapImageRep I get a frame duration of `0.15s` for the first gif and `0.1s` for the second.
But 0.1 is way to slow for the second gif.

When using imagemagick I also get `0.15s` for the first, but `0.03s` for the second gif, which is correct.

Am I doing something wrong, or is NSBitmapImageRep, i.e. using NSImageView for displaying gifs useless and I would have to resort back to a webview (which can display both gifs correctly)?

Comment: You do nothing wrong. NSBitmapImageRep uses the DelayTime (0.1 sec  in your second gif) instead of the UnclampedDelayTime (0.03 sec).  Both values are shown in the Preview app and in the corresponding CGImage (every NSBitmapImageRep is a CGImage under the hood). But NSBitmapImageRep uses the clamped value, because it thinks 0.03 sec is too fast (and you think 0.1 sec is too slow). It should be possible to change these values for each frame in the NSBitmapImageRep using setProperty:NSImageCurrentFrameDuration withValue:@0.03 But my first experiments failed, still going on.

Comment: This are just example gifs, I'll have to handle unknown gifs, so hard coding 0.03 won't work. So basically I would have to read the info from the gif file myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Heinrich I now know that the gif as two values, the real one and the clamped value. Sadly NSBitmapImageRep only provides the clamped value, but with CGImageProperty I can read both values. So I iterate through each frame, update the duration with the correct one and in the end create a CAAnimation like in: https://github.com/orta/GIFs/blob/master/objc/GIFs/ORImageView.m

So this is the code for updating the duration:

```
NSDictionary *properties = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, i, nil);
float duration = [[[properties objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary]
                   objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *) kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime] doubleValue];
[bitmapRepresentation setProperty:NSImageCurrentFrame withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
[bitmapRepresentation setProperty:NSImageCurrentFrameDuration withValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:duration]];
```